# MySQL - can't define foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, wamp

I'm trying to create tables on Wamp server using Python. There are two tables - person and message. The table message has a column person_id which should be a foreign key for table person.

After the tables are created, there is no foreign key in message table when I look at it via PhpMyAdmin. Is there something wrong with SQL queries?

Creation of person:

```
@staticmethod
def createTablePerson():
    return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (" \
           "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY," \
           "name VARCHAR(100)," \
           "surname VARCHAR(100)" \
           ");"
```

Creation of message:

```
@staticmethod
def createTableMessage():
    return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (" \
           "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY," \
           "personID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES person (id)," \
           "text VARCHAR(1000)" \
           ");"
```

Comment: Could you check you table's engine, as foreign keys are unimplemented and silently ignored for MyISAM tables, and will only work with InnoDB tables.

Comment: MySQL parses but *ignores* "inline REFERENCES specifications"  (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses *only* when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MySQL parses but ignores “inline `REFERENCES` specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts `REFERENCES` clauses only when specified as part of a separate `FOREIGN KEY` specification.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

---

So, to add a foreign key constraint (for storage engines that support them), the foreign key has to be defined separately from the column.

With this, the REFERENCES clause is ignored:

```
personID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES person (id),
```

To have MySQL add a foreign key constraint, do it like this:

```
personID INT NOT NULL, 
...
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES person (id),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `index` the column before adding as foreign key. The commands should be as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
           id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
           name VARCHAR(100),
           surname VARCHAR(100)
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
           id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
           text VARCHAR(1000),
           personID INT NOT NULL,
           INDEX personid_idx (personID),
           FOREIGN KEY (personID)  REFERENCES person (id)

           );
```

Comment: A unique or primary key on the referenced table column is enough.

Comment: This syntax will work, because the REFERENCES clause is part of a separate FOREIGN KEY definition. But there is no requirement to add an INDEX or KEY on the column to have a foreign key defined. (InnoDB will automatically create an index if a suitable index does not already exist.)